# How to Sum a Range that I Offset?

Tags: vba, sum, offset

I have some code that populates data on the next empty column. I do this by using the (x1ToEnd) feature.

However, I am trying to do the same feature with a sum of a range of multiple cells (the ones I want to sum) within my WorksheetFunction.SUM function but the whole range is not working, only the very first cell populates.

Check out my code

```
range("b8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = 
WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A4:A7").End(xlToRight).Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I follow what you're doing. Does this help?

```
Range("b8").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
                             WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Resize(4))
```

Comment: This worked, I was trying to do this for 2 hours. 

Thank you a ton!